# Proving multiplicative identity

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let multiplication denoted by $\bigotimes$.

$a$ $\bigotimes$ $b$ = $a^{\log b}$

prove that there exists a multiplicative identity.

Comment: On what set is this operation defined?

Answer (score 1):

If
$a\bigotimes b = a$
for all $a$,
then
$a
= a^{\log b}
$
so
$\log b = 1$.
Therefore
$b$ is whatever the log base is.

If
$a\bigotimes b = b$
for all $b$,
then
$b
= a^{\log b}
$
or
$\log b
= (\log b)(\log a)
$
so $\log a = 1$.

Therefore,
the "multiplicative" identity
is whatever the
base of the log is.